# How to debug server-side code in SvelteKit using Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vite, sveltekit

I would like to debug server side code (+server.svelte) code in VS code but cannot work out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on `debugger` statements isn't that great, but fortunately there is a better solution (using the `node-loader` module from `vavite`): https://www.codelantis.com/blog/sveltekit-server-debugging-vscode-webstorm

Answer (score 5):

Server-side debugging is possible, but not fully supported:

- You can trigger the debugger with `debugger` statements.
- Or breakpoints in the *compiled* code.
- Breakpoints in uncompiled Svelte/TS source files will [not work](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1144) because of a [Vite issue with sourcemaps](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3288).

You need to attach the VS code debugger to the SvelteKit dev server. This is one way to do this: https://app.arcade.software/share/RIrEisEk7V36paQmqtNI

Comment: This is great. I had it working with this but it just suddenly just stopped. It gave me a warning about multiple lock files when I ran the debugger. I found a pnpm one (I use npm). I removed it but same issue, unbound breakpoints. Any pointers to what I could do to get it back working again?