# How can I get debugging working on both client and server side code for SvelteKit inside VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger, sveltekit

How can I get debugging to work in VS Code (and not in the Chrome debugger) for both the server and client?  I can't get breakpoints to hit in my server-side code in my .ts files.

I do know there is an issue with Vite and debugging in VS Code for the server side.  Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

I actually finally have debugging working on both the client and server for SvelteKit in VS Code.

It was kind of convoluted the way I had to go about getting all the debugging just to work.  I'll lay out the steps here in case anyone else needs to debug both client/server in VS Code.  It actually works pretty seamlessly having breakpoints on both sides and they are both hit.  Almost like the two aren't actually separate.

1. Create a launch config for the server side.

   ```json
   {
        "type": "node-terminal",
        "name": "Run Script: dev",
        "request": "launch",
        "command": "npm run devv",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
   }
   ```
2. Create a launch config for chrome:

   ```json
   {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:5173",
        "port": 5173,
        "smartStep": true,
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**",
            "node_modules/**",
            "/**/*.js",
            "/**/*.css",
            "/*\\.js"
        ],
        "userDataDir": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/chrome"
   }
   ```
3. I got the next steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75539100/5798864)
   The server side code debugging is currently not supported in Vite in VS Code.  But there
   is a workaround. This will show you how to attach to the dev server, BUT it uses
   generated vite files and not your ts source maps. https://app.arcade.software/share/RIrEisEk7V36paQmqtNI
4. To get around the problem of not being able to put breakpoints in your actual .ts files
   and have them hit, is with using VAVite.  I found this from here https://github.com/cyco130/vavite/pull/17

   Install @vavite/node-loader as a dev dependency. `npm install --save-dev @vavite/node-loader`

   Add `import { nodeLoaderPlugin } from "@vavite/node-loader/plugin"` to your Vite config

   Add `nodeLoaderPlugin()` to your Vite plugins

   ```js
   plugins: [
       nodeLoaderPlugin(),
       sveltekit()
   ]
   ```

Run your project with `vavite-loader vite dev` (or `vavite-loader rakkas dev`, `vavite-loader astro dev`, etc.)

Here's the project and the plugin if you want more info. https://github.com/cyco130/vavite/tree/main/packages/node-loader

5. Once you have vavite node-loader installed change your package.json to add a command (I named it devv eg: `"devv": "vavite-loader vite dev"`, this way it uses vavite command to start the server.  And with this you can now run the first config I showed in the debugger and it will start vavite, the vite dev server, and attach to it, and breakpoints can be hit in your ts files.
6. Once that debug config starts, then choose the Launch Chrome config from the debug drop down, and run it.  Now chrome is attached to VS Code for the front end.  So breakpoints will be hit in .svelte files and client side load functions, etc inside of VS Code. And then server side will be hit from the last config (in VS Code as well).  No need to use the chrome debugger anymore for either client/server.

And if someone has an easier setup than this they'd like to share that would be great!

Comment: For me the `nodeLoaderPlugin()` function call gives the error `Type 'Plugin_2' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<Plugin_2[]>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]`.